# While creating API Gateway in google cloud platform throwing unreachable error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager, google-api-gateway

While I was trying to create an api gateway it is failing sometimes and showing the following error[image]

But it is not happening always. But it is occurring a noticeable amount of times. Any idea what might be the problem? I don't have any problem with the API specs. I was trying to create api gateway just after waiting 90 seconds right after creating a new api gateway config from the OpenAPI specs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 429 status code is due to too many requests. You are being rate limited.